# Jndi spring issue

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jndi, jdbctemplate

I'm looking for using Spring and JNDI but I can't find the problem here :

My Server.xml:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/MimsDS"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      username="xxx" password="xxx"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.3:1526:mimsdb10"
      maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
      validationQuery="select sysdate from dual"
    />
```

My application-Context :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MimsDS" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /> 
  </bean>

<bean id="simpleJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
</bean>
```

I got this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarDaoImpl' defined in file [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0/webapps/op-calendar/WEB-INF/classes/be/mims/opcalendar/services/CalendarDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `JndiObjectFactoryBean`, not `JndiTemplate`.